# error on \Device\Harddisk11\DR26 but Disk 11 doesn't exist

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

On a Windows 2008R2 server, I am getting this message in Event Viewer:

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Disk
Date:          7/3/2013 4:25:54 AM
Event ID:      51
Task Category: None
Level:         Warning
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Description:
An error was detected on device \Device\Harddisk11\DR26 during a paging operation.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Disk" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="32772">51</EventID>
    <Level>3</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-07-03T08:25:54.828401000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>115066</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>\Device\Harddisk11\DR26</Data>
    <Binary>030080000100000000000000330004802D0100000E0000C000000000000000000000000000000000BE009A0500000000FFFFFFFF010000005800000802000008FD200A1242032040000200003C0000001080838780FAFFFF483DF28780FAFFFF0000000000000000D0285A0281FAFFFF0000000000000000008841060000000028000641880000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000</Binary>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

However, there is no disk 11 on this server. The disks stop at 10.

[image: disk management mmc showing disks 9, 10, and the DVD drive]

This particular server is a Hyper-V host in a cluster. All of the disks are either CSV disks or pass-through disks, all backed by iSCSI.

How can I identify which drive this is?

`wmic` does not list the drive:

```
Caption                                     DeviceID             Model                                       Partitions  Size
LEFTHAND iSCSIDisk  Multi-Path Disk Device  \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE5   LEFTHAND iSCSIDisk  Multi-Path Disk Device  1           2418923243520
LEFTHAND iSCSIDisk  Multi-Path Disk Device  \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE9   LEFTHAND iSCSIDisk  Multi-Path Disk Device  1           1069286400
LEFTHAND iSCSIDisk  Multi-Path Disk Device  \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE10  LEFTHAND iSCSIDisk  Multi-Path Disk Device  1           1759214661120
LEFTHAND iSCSIDisk  Multi-Path Disk Device  \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE4   LEFTHAND iSCSIDisk  Multi-Path Disk Device  1           1979117521920
LEFTHAND iSCSIDisk  Multi-Path Disk Device  \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE7   LEFTHAND iSCSIDisk  Multi-Path Disk Device  1           80525491200
LEFTHAND iSCSIDisk  Multi-Path Disk Device  \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE8   LEFTHAND iSCSIDisk  Multi-Path Disk Device  1           536864025600
LEFTHAND iSCSIDisk  Multi-Path Disk Device  \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2   LEFTHAND iSCSIDisk  Multi-Path Disk Device  1           536864025600
LEFTHAND iSCSIDisk  Multi-Path Disk Device  \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE3   LEFTHAND iSCSIDisk  Multi-Path Disk Device  1           536864025600
LEFTHAND iSCSIDisk  Multi-Path Disk Device  \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1   LEFTHAND iSCSIDisk  Multi-Path Disk Device  1           322118415360
LEFTHAND iSCSIDisk  Multi-Path Disk Device  \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE6   LEFTHAND iSCSIDisk  Multi-Path Disk Device  0           1069286400
HP LOGICAL VOLUME SCSI Disk Device          \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0   HP LOGICAL VOLUME SCSI Disk Device          2           220122071040
```

Comment: Has there never been a disk 11? That error is usually caused by an unclean dismount.

Comment: I have no idea. Do you know how to find out? Perhaps by snooping through the registry?

Comment: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP might be a place to look. You can also try "wmic diskdrive list brief" from cmd

Comment: @dusan.bajic no joy on either.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a [WAG](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=WAG&defid=1027073) but have you tried recompiling the iSCSI [MOF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa823192%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) files? I've come across similar behavior where NetApp's SnapDrive can't enumerate all the of the iSCSI drives on a particular server. This [blog](http://koenraadrens.wordpress.com/2012/01/04/snapdrive-doesnt-show-disks-and-iscsi-management-is-missing/) pointed me at this [KB2001997](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2001997).

Try comparing the results of the following WMI query on this server to another known good one:

```
Get-WmiObject -NameSpace Root\WMI MSiSCSIInitiator_PersistentDevices
```